# List Component: How to detect which item was selected?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I can access a list (as a container of items) in a controller but I do not know how to access list items properties.

How to create the correct [ComponentQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery) rule? I tried 'list > item' but it does not work.

Each item has it's title but I get 'undefined' as output in selectSection.

```
Ext.define( 'UGP.controller.BeginList',
            {               
                extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
                config:
                {
                    views: [ 'BeginList' ],
                    control:
                    {
                        'list':
                        {
                            select: 'selectSection'
                        }
                    }
                },

                selectSection: function()
                {
                    Ext.Msg.alert( 'title=' + this.title );
                }
            }
);
```

The BeginList.js with the list component:

```
Ext.define( 'UGP.view.BeginList',
            {
                extend: 'Ext.List',

                config:
                {
                    fullscreen: true,
                    itemTpl: '{title}',
                    data: 
                    [
                        { title: 'Chapter 1', id: 0, action: "selectSection" },
                        { title: 'Chapter 2', id: 1, action: "selectSection" },
                        { title: 'Chapter 3', id: 2, action: "selectSection" },
                        { title: 'Chapter 4', id: 3, action: "selectSection" }
                    ]
                }
            }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in the [`select`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List-event-select) event documentation that it passes arguments. So you can change the signature of your `selectSection` function to this :

```
selectSection: function (list, record) {
  Ext.Msg.alert( 'title=' + record.get( 'title' ) );
}
```

You can also take a look at the [`itemTap`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List-event-itemtap) event which usually the one used to detect tap events on a list item.

Hope this helps